# Azure VIP for multiple SSL on single VM

Tags: azure

I got an Azure VM (Virtual Machine) with two websites. 
Each website has its own SSL certificate

However, the VM only has one internal IP address, so it doesn't work.

What I want to do is to add a second VIP (virtual IP), and map that to a different port. 
So something like this:

VIP 1.1.1.1:80 points to 192.168.1.1:8081

VIP 2.2.2.2:80 points to 192.168.1.1:8082

VIP 3.3.3.3:443 points to 192.168.1.1:8444

VIP 4.4.4.4:443 points to 192.168.1.1:8445

I think this should work, however, I ran into a lot of trouble configuring Azure. For some reason there is no web interface to define these things, and I simply didn't manage yet to do this through any of the suggested methods.

Can someone help me?

1. Should my solution work?
2. How do I do this?

I found this article: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/load-balancer-multivip/

using Microsoft Azure PowerShell, trying to add / list the VIP's, I get Get-AzureDeployment : ResourceNotFound: No deployments were found.

Comment: The article in question talks about the classic deployment, whilst my servers are in ARM (Azure Resource Manager). The two systems work differently with different capabilities. Unfortunately also when trying to set up the classic server, it still gives me the "No deployments were found", so I never actually got that to work either.

Comment: I also found that there is a very low limit (1 for basic / step in servers) for NIC's (virtual network cards). Also people say that the extra NIC is only for internal networking.

Comment: The load balancer does have an interface, and the settings in the web UI are the same as the PowerShell commands. The load balancer is quite nice, it allows you to set rules or simply put a NAT. There is however only one incoming IP per load balancer. Unfortunately it won't allow you to add a second load balancer with the same backend pool / server, which is exactly what I needed. The message it gives is "Only one internal and one public load balancer are allowed per availability set."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed, it works, I'm happy. 
My thanks goes out to Siva Edupuganti, senior programmer Azure who helped me with this.

**So, what did I do to get it to work?**

**The short answer is that wtih azure powershell script You can setup multiple frontend IP address configurations on a single load balancer. Each frontend IP address configuration has an IP address.** Through the UI you can't do this.

The long answer is the final configuration to get this done:

1. My site can still be served on my standard port: 80 & 443.
2. I added 5 new IP's (virtual IP's)

Each incoming request on this new public virtual IP will be mapped by the load balancer to the internal IP with a

different port. I will use load balancing rules for this. So incoming will always be on the standar ports 80 and 443,

but the IIS will receive on port 81 and 4431.

vip-81 80 => 81, 443 => 4431

vip-82 80 => 82, 443 => 4432

vip-83 80 => 83, 443 => 4433

vip-84 80 => 84, 443 => 4434

vip-85 80 => 85, 443 => 4435

First prepare IP's through Azure UI. 
There is a maximum of 5 frontendpool addresses, so I created 5.

vip-81
vip-82
vip-83
vip-84
vip-85

```
#scripting part:
#Now login with Azure Powershell:
Login-AzureRmAccount

#You can run this scripts line by line or all together:
$publicIP1 = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -name vip-81 -resourcegroupname MyRG
$publicIP2 = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -name vip-82 -resourcegroupname MyRG
$publicIP3 = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -name vip-83 -resourcegroupname MyRG
$publicIP4 = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -name vip-84 -resourcegroupname MyRG
$publicIP5 = Get-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -name vip-85 -resourcegroupname MyRG

$frontendIP1 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name lb-feipc-1 -PublicIpAddress $publicIP1
$frontendIP2 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name lb-feipc-2 -PublicIpAddress $publicIP2 
$frontendIP3 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name lb-feipc-3 -PublicIpAddress $publicIP3 
$frontendIP4 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name lb-feipc-4 -PublicIpAddress $publicIP4
$frontendIP5 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerFrontendIpConfig -Name lb-feipc-5 -PublicIpAddress $publicIP5

$beaddresspool = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerBackendAddressPoolConfig -Name lb-beapc-grp1

$lbrule1 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-80-8081 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP1 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 80 -BackendPort 8081
$lbrule2 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-80-8082 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP2 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 80 -BackendPort 8082
$lbrule3 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-80-8083 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP3 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 80 -BackendPort 8083
$lbrule4 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-80-8084 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP4 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 80 -BackendPort 8084
$lbrule5 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-80-8085 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP5 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 80 -BackendPort 8085

$lbrule6 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-443-4431 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP1 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 443 -BackendPort 4431 
$lbrule7 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-443-4432 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP2 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 443 -BackendPort 4432
$lbrule8 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-443-4433 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP3 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 443 -BackendPort 4433
$lbrule9 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-443-4434 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP4 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 443 -BackendPort 4434
$lbrule10 = New-AzureRmLoadBalancerRuleConfig -Name lb-rule-tcp-443-4435 -FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP5 -

BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool -Protocol Tcp -FrontendPort 443 -BackendPort 4435

$NRPLB = New-AzureRmLoadBalancer -ResourceGroupName MyRG -Name lb-grp1 -Location 'Central US' -

FrontendIpConfiguration $frontendIP1,$frontendIP2,$frontendIP3,$frontendIP4,$frontendIP5 -LoadBalancingRule $lbrule1,

$lbrule2,$lbrule3,$lbrule4,$lbrule5,$lbrule6,$lbrule7,$lbrule8,$lbrule9,$lbrule10 -BackendAddressPool $beAddressPool

#end script part. Go to the UI.
```

Now the load balancer is set with 10 rules for the port mapping.

Now open a few ports and other settings through UI:

1. the network security group to allow port * to port 8081-8085 and 4431-4435
2. the network security group to allow any from AzureLoadBalancer to port 8081-8085
3. open the windows firewall on port 8081-8085 and 4431-4435

Now:
**Configure load balancer through UI: add to the backend pool associate with web server / pool.**

And prepare probes & connect to load balancing rules in UI (will work without as well)

lb-probe-tcp-8081

lb-probe-tcp-8082

lb-probe-tcp-8083

lb-probe-tcp-8084

lb-probe-tcp-8085

And now it should all work. 6 IP's, of which 5 through load balancer. And up to 6 different SSL certificates running side by side on the same virtual server with IIS.